# Integrate ZXing without the use of a 3rd party scanner?

Tags: android, zxing

I've read numerous topics already where people asked how to integrate ZXing in an Android application where they necessarily need to have a 3rd party scanner app installed in order to scan a QR Code.

That's exactly what i want to do too. This is what i have done so far:

I downloaded the ZXing project. I copied all the relevant source code to my Android application. So far so good, it all compiles fine. When i press on a button in my app it opens a small dialog asking what barcode scanner i want to use. I have the following options:

1. QR-Droid (3rd party app)
2. My own app

When i use the first option, then the camera gets activated and i can scan a QR code. But when i use the 2nd option (my own app), then nothing happends. I thought ZXing came with a scanner too, so that a 3rd party QR scanner isn't necessary??

But maybe there are other steps i have to take aswell? This is how my manifest looks like:

Added this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And in a button action i have:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");         
intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");  
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Is there any way to make a QR Scanner start without the need of a 3rd party scanner?? I have all the source imported in my project.

Comment: Do *not* start by copying our app!

Comment: @SeanOwen Then don't make it open source...

Comment: We make it open source so you can reuse code, and make better innovative apps -- not so you can clone it for profit. You are aware that open source doesn't mean "do whatever you want", not even legally? For example, you are not granted trademark rights, and cloning our UI is therefore not legal. Dangerous attitude...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your Manifest and add this

```
 <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

also add camera permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

and implemetn onActivityResult method in your Activity

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
    {
        if (requestCode == 0) 
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Log.i("xZing", "contents: "+contents+" format: "+format);
                // Handle successful scan
            } 
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }
    }
```

for more information or any trouble see [this](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/) link

Comment: Thanks alot, you really helped me out!! +2 for you

Comment: No. Do *not* declare your app to respond to Intents intended for another app!

Comment: I respect and understand what you want to say...So developer need to change xZing library manifest file to avoid using the same intent filter?.

Comment: What you need is to write your own AndroidManifest.xml, and your own app to start. Then make it respond to your own Intents.

Comment: Okay..I understand...actually I was follow this [blog](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/). Today i seen that blog is updated as you say.

Answer (score 3):

This is confused, and the approach you have accepted is harmful.

First, please do not copy our app wholesale, as we have repeatedly stressed here. It is not only discouraged, but violates our trademark if you clone the UI. Just don't do it.

Second, you are copying our code, but then are trying to use a scanner by Intent. Why? If you want to use Intents, you don't need to use any code.

Third, you are declaring your app to respond to *our* app Intent. You are intercepting calls intended for Barcode Scanner. If you can reply in exactly the same way, OK, but, I imagine you are not guaranteeing this. By doing so you're harming users of Barcode Scanner, the open source project you're profiting from.